# BIM 360 GLUE Viwer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

How can i view the model which is uploaded to GLUE ?

Is there a JavaScript viewer available for viewing glue model ?

I am able to Login and Upload to model to glue, but trying to view using iframe the error occured.

**Refused to display 'https://b2-staging.autodesk.com/?&company_id=xxxxxxxxx&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**

Comment: On one of our blogs, it indicates: Glue viewer, which is a plugin, is no longer supported by modern browses. https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/lab3-glue-api-web-intro/  I will double check with engineer team, while may I firstly know which OS, OS version,  and which browser and version you are testing with?

Comment: is it possible to implement Model Coordinate in Forge for viewing Clash ?

Comment: sure, if by BIM 360 Model Coordination API.  we have produced a few samples and tutorials. e.g. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-clash-view-model-coordination-api-nodejs is a demo on viewing clash inside Forge Viewer.  you could find more blogs by the keyword 'clash', and tutorials on https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/model-coordination/